# Litespeed cache coverts images to webp bit Facebook don't show webp images in urls

Tags: facebook

I'm using WordPress with Litespeed cache to speedup my images and convert them to webp like Google tells me to, but when I add a link to any page or post to Facebook the image is blank. My website is https://webhoney.com.au/

There's no setting to serve jpeg on Facebook or serve as both. Has anyone else got this problem?

I tried adding an og:image in the header of my theme so Facebook could maybe just serve the one image for all, just to test, but even that doesn't show. I have gone to the facebook debug page and it says Results from reviewing your URLs

URLs Reviewed1

Resultshttps://webhoney.com.auNo Issues

Any clues?

Thanks

[image: Facebook image error when adding page and post links served by WordPress as WebP]